# Looking for a way outside of instruments to validate and check any retain cycles

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Instruments is a cumbersome tool and it's memory leak check often doesn't find retain cycles.  Example:  A delegate pattern where the delegate isn't weak creates a retain cycle for sure, but somehow the leak doesn't show up.  Surely a retain cycle is a leak?
Looking for a logging mechanism outside of instruments - code that I can embed into my project to detect this.

Comment: It's a good idea to stick to one language tag for a question. If you want an answer in multiple languages then post two questions, each with one language tag. You can always edit the questions to add a link to each other.

Comment: A retain cycle is not always a leak. It depends whether the memory is reachable, and that kind of retain cycle is often desirable (it's used commonly in dispatch queues and NSURLConnection/Session for instance to keep things around until they complete, and then automatically release themselves; NSURLSession.delegate is intentionally a strong property, not a weak one). The new memory graph tool in Xcode 8 is what you're looking for, though.

Comment: @ColGraff equally applies to Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: @RobNapier Was looking for a programmatic way of logging them.  Interesting note you raise.  Not sure I follow that a retain cycle is not a memory leak - please explain more.  Just because NSURLSession using a strong delegate - doesn't this just mean that the calling class shouldn't own the session but it's really vice versa.  Storing the session as a strong reference will create a retain cycle and memory leak.  Note - I tried the new memory graph tool and it didn't find it (as discussed with the Apple Engineers @ WWDC this is a bug!).

Comment: Take a look at https://code.facebook.com/posts/583946315094347/automatic-memory-leak-detection-on-ios/.

Comment: A retain cycle is only a problem if it can never be broken. When a NSURLSession completes, it releases its delegate, so the cycle is broken and everything can deallocate. So cycles are sometimes intentional. A cycle is not a leak (even when it is a mistake) if there is a path to it, even weakly, from live objects. That's why the leak tool can't find them in all cases. Many "leaks" aren't leaks at all but just abandoned. For instance, devs often forget to remove things from caches and they "leak" (but it's not technically a leak or a cycle, just abandoned).

Comment: @RobNapier Interesting.  Can you give an example of abandonment so I can understand your example.

Comment: The most common is things left in cache dictionaries. Another really common case is repeatedly adding subviews to table view cells (so you get more and more layers of views you can't actually see). Another is accidentally keeping around raw JSON data after you've parsed it. All kinds of ways to have memory hang around because you just forgot to get rid of it.

Comment: OK thanks.  Subviews of a cell should get disposed of as soon as the cell is disposed, which should be fairly frequent.  But anyone, I get what you are saying thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this manual logger that you can to the init of classes you are analyzing:

```
struct WeakStruct {
   weak var weakObject: AnyObject?
  let objectName: String
}


public class RetainCycleLogger {
     var weakStructs = [WeakStruct]()
     public static let sharedInstance = RetainCycleLogger()

     public func addObject(object: AnyObject) {
          weakStructs.append(WeakStruct(weakObject: object, objectName: classNameAsString(object)))
     }

     func count(object: AnyObject) -> Int {
         let classname = classNameAsString(object)
         return weakStructs.filter({$0.objectName == classname}).flatMap({$0.weakObject}).count
     }

     func classNameAsString(obj: Any) -> String {
         return String(reflecting: obj)
     }

     public func printAllCounts() {
         let classes = weakStructs.filter({$0.weakObject != nil}).map({$0.objectName})
         let uniqueClasses: [String] = Array(Set(classes))
         for className in uniqueClasses {
             print("---- Class: \(className) \(classes.filter({$0 == className}).count)")
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Also available here with examples https://github.com/nickm01/RetainCycleLoggerExample